# Jquery ToastMessage - only show close for specific toast types?

Tags: php, jquery, toast, message

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask.. but here goes.

I use this jquery plug in :

http://akquinet.github.io/jquery-toastmessage-plugin/

It works well.. but I would only like the close gif to appear for sticky messages, not messages that fade away.

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry looks like I posted to soon :(

Changing this :

```
i=c("<div></div>").addClass("toast-item-close").prependTo(d).html(g.closeText).click(function(){c().toastmessage("removeToast",d,g)
});
```

to this:

```
if (g.sticky) {i=c("<div></div>").addClass("toast-item-close").prependTo(d).html(g.closeText).click(function(){c().toastmessage("removeToast",d,g)
}); }
```

Seems to have worked..